# Using jquery autocomplete, how do I test for the current object inside the parse function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

I have some jquery autocomplete code like that below:

```
$('[name$=_ID]').autocomplete('<%=Url.Action("GetMatchingParts", "ServiceReport") %>',     {
            minChars: 3,
            dataType: 'json',
            parse: function(data) {
                var rows = new Array();
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    rows[i] = { data: data[i], value: data[i].ID, result: data[i].ID };
                }
                return rows;
            },
            formatItem: function(row) {
                return row.ID + "<br />" + row.Name;
            },
            max: 100,
            delay: 500,
            cacheLength: 1,
            matchContains: true,
            autofill: true,
            selectFirst: false,
            highlight: false,
            multiple: false
        });
```

I have several text boxes on the page that end with _ID and need to use the autocomplete. Depending on other things happening on the page, I will sometimes set the readonly attribute to true for a single text box.

How can I disable the autocomplete or return 0 rows when the readonly attribute is set to true for a specific text box?

Comment: When `readonly='readonly'`, won't typing in the `input` be impossible?

Comment: Yes, but if I click in that field, the autocomplete drops down and I can't get out of it because it's readonly and won't allow me to select anything.

Comment: Can't you just disable the dropdown at the same time you set the textbox to `readonly`?

Comment: Well, how would I do that Joseph? $('[name_ID]').autocomplete("disable"); ?

Answer (score 1):

By the time you set 'readOnly', add the below statement.

```
  $( "#yourControlID" ).autocomplete({ disabled: true });
```

Or

```
$( "#yourControlID" ).autocomplete( "disable" );
```

Comment: It looks like this can only be set when first initializing the autocomplete. After init, need to use this: $( ".selector" ).autocomplete( "option", "disabled", true ); Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Going to try this now.